# Replacing Subqueries with Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've been rewriting a query using extensive subqueries for the output columns (massive tables so 45 seconds currently). There are applicants (aka Comp), enquiries and events (aka GS). When an applicant has an enquiry of a certain type and an event of a certain type that corresponds to the enquiry type, they get included, so I've paired the criteria in the join.

I've tried to rewrite the columns using a pivot table, but is this the right approach? One disadvantage is sometimes two enquiry types match one event type and I've had to split them out.

SQL USed:

```
CREATE TABLE F_ENQUIRY  (
          E_KEY VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
          E_APP_LINK VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
          E_DATE_REG datetime NOT NULL, 
          E_PRIORITY_LINK int NOT NULL, 
          PRIMARY KEY(E_KEY)
          )
GO

CREATE TABLE F_EVENTS  (
          EVENT_NO int, 
          EVENT_KEY VARCHAR(15), 
          EVENT_APP_LINK VARCHAR(15),
          EVENT_DATE datetime,
          EVENT_TYPE int,
          EVENT_TYPE_LINK int,
          PRIMARY KEY(EVENT_NO)
          )

GO

CREATE TABLE F_APPLICANT  (
          "A_KEY" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY(A_KEY)
          )
GO

INSERT INTO F_ENQUIRY (E_KEY,E_APP_LINK,E_DATE_REG,E_PRIORITY_LINK) VALUES 
('303+1001','303+10019','2020-01-12 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1002','303+10019','2015-03-03 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1003','303+10019','2002-01-18 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1004','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1005','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1006','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1007','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1008','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',65)
,('303+1016','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',20)
,('303+1017','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',20)
,('303+1018','303+10029','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',20)
,('303+1019','303+10019','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',33)
,('303+1020','303+10019','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',33)
,('303+1021','303+10019','2019-04-29 00:00:00.000',33)

GO

INSERT INTO F_EVENTS (EVENT_NO,EVENT_KEY,EVENT_APP_LINK,EVENT_DATE,EVENT_TYPE,EVENT_TYPE_LINK) VALUES 
(893693,'303+1001','303+10019','2019-11-13 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(840905,'303+1002','303+10019','2019-06-28 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(893694,'303+1003','303+10019','2019-11-13 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(893695,'303+1004','303+10029','2019-11-13 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(781122,'303+1005','303+10029','2019-02-14 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(784170,'303+1001','303+10029','2019-02-20 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(788124,'303+1002','303+10029','2019-03-01 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(795941,'303+1003','303+10029','2019-03-25 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(797944,'303+1004','303+10029','2019-03-27 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(802037,'303+1005','303+10029','2019-03-28 00:00:00.000',1308,99)
,(821342,'303+1013','303+10029','2019-05-10 00:00:00.000',1308,130)
,(826063,'303+1014','303+10029','2019-05-29 00:00:00.000',1308,130)
,(828412,'303+1015','303+10029','2019-05-30 00:00:00.000',1308,130)
,(831525,'303+1016','303+10029','2019-06-07 00:00:00.000',1308,130)
,(833202,'303+1017','303+10029','2019-06-11 00:00:00.000',1308,130)
,(837145,'303+1019','303+10019','2019-06-21 00:00:00.000',1308,143)
,(842768,'303+1020','303+10019','2019-07-19 00:00:00.000',1308,143)
,(845624,'303+1021','303+10019','2019-07-30 00:00:00.000',1308,143)
,(848579,'303+1022','303+10019','2019-08-06 00:00:00.000',1308,143)
,(851026,'303+1023','303+10019','2019-08-13 00:00:00.000',1308,143)

GO

INSERT INTO F_APPLICANT (a_key) VALUES 
('303+10019'),
('303+10029')

GO

select
    distinct a_key as Comp_Link,
    EandGS.GS_Type_Link,
    EandGS.GS_Date,
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (69,65)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "A Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (34)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "B Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (27,
        50)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "C Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (28)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "D Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (26)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "E Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (20)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "F Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (36)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "G Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (33)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "H Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (23)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "I Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (25)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "J Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (24,
        43)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "K Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (72)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "L Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (22,
        14)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "M Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (21)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "N Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (30)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "O Date",
    (
    select
        max(e_date_reg)
    from
        f_enquiry
    where
        e_app_link = a_key
        and e_priority_link in (73)
        and e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020') as "P Date"
from
    f_enquiry
inner join f_applicant on
    e_app_link = a_key
inner join (
    select
        a_key as Comp_Link,
        e_priority_link as Enq_Type,
        e_date_reg as Enq_Date_Reg,
        event_type_link as GS_Type_Link,
        event_no as GS_No,
        event_date as GS_Date
    from
        f_applicant
    inner join f_enquiry on
        e_app_link = a_key
    inner join f_events on
        event_app_link = a_key
    where
        e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
        and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020'
        and event_date >= '01/APR/2019'
        and event_date <= '31/MAR/2020'
        and event_type = 1308
        and (
            (e_priority_link in (69,65) and event_type_link = 99) 
            or (e_priority_link = 34 and event_type_link = 144)
            or (e_priority_link in (50,27) and event_type_link in (400067,80))
            or (e_priority_link = 28 and event_type_link = 136)
            or (e_priority_link = 26 and event_type_link = 135)
            or (e_priority_link = 20 and event_type_link = 130)
            or (e_priority_link = 36 and event_type_link = 146)
            or (e_priority_link = 33 and event_type_link = 143)
            or (e_priority_link = 23 and event_type_link = 133)
            or (e_priority_link in (25,43) and event_type_link = 82)
            or (e_priority_link in (24,43) and event_type_link = 134)
            or (e_priority_link = 72 and event_type_link = 400297)
            or (e_priority_link in (14,22) and event_type_link in (400071,84))
            or (e_priority_link = 30 and event_type_link = 132)
            or (e_priority_link = 21 and event_type_link = 131)
            or (e_priority_link = 73 and event_type_link = 140)
        )
) as EandGS on Comp_Link = a_key

GO

WITH EandGS AS (
select
    a_key as Comp_Link,
    event_type_link as GS_Type_Link,
    event_date as GS_Date,
    event_no as GS_No,
    e_priority_link as Enq_Type,
    e_date_reg as Enq_Date_Reg
from
    f_applicant
inner join f_enquiry on
    e_app_link = a_key
inner join f_events on
    event_app_link = a_key
where
    e_date_reg >= '01/APR/2019'
    and e_date_reg <= '31/MAR/2020'
    and event_date >= '01/APR/2019'
    and event_date <= '31/MAR/2020'
    and event_type = 1308
    and ((e_priority_link in (69,65) and event_type_link = 99) 
    or (e_priority_link = 34 and event_type_link = 144)
    or (e_priority_link in (50,27) and event_type_link in (400067,80))
    or (e_priority_link = 28 and event_type_link = 136)
    or (e_priority_link = 26 and event_type_link = 135)
    or (e_priority_link = 20 and event_type_link = 130)
    or (e_priority_link = 36 and event_type_link = 146)
    or (e_priority_link = 33 and event_type_link = 143)
    or (e_priority_link = 23 and event_type_link = 133)
    or (e_priority_link in (25,43) and event_type_link = 82)
    or (e_priority_link in (24,43) and event_type_link = 134)
    or (e_priority_link = 72 and event_type_link = 400297)
    or (e_priority_link in (14,22) and event_type_link in (400071,84))
    or (e_priority_link = 30 and event_type_link = 132)
    or (e_priority_link = 21 and event_type_link = 131)
    or (e_priority_link = 73 and event_type_link = 140))
    ),
E AS (
select Comp_Link,Enq_Type,Enq_Date_Reg from EandGS --Used by pivot table to stop duplicate rows caused by columns not included
),
EP AS (
select Comp_Link,[14],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[30],[33],[34],[36],[43],[50],[65],[69],[72],[73]
from
E PIVOT (max(E.Enq_Date_Reg) FOR E.Enq_Type IN ([14],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[30],[33],[34],[36],[43],[50],[65],[69],[72],[73])) as pvt
)
select distinct EandGS.Comp_Link,GS_Type_Link,GS_Date,GS_No,[14],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[30],[33],[34],[36],[43],[50],[65],[69],[72],[73]
from EandGS
inner join EP on EP.Comp_Link = EandGS.Comp_Link
order by EandGS.Comp_Link asc
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=77bcaa044db38ee2e1d701905429f316)

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would really clarify your issue.

Comment: It's not an image, @Sami , it was a DB<>Fiddle. I've copied all the SQL out of it on behalf of the OP.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off with a Cross-Tab. [Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 1 – Converting Rows to Columns](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%E2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1)